# how to store mutiple variable in session as multi dimension array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

i have 3 form files like form1.php ,form2.php, form3.php and a index.php file and a output.php file
in these form1 ,form2, form3  files i have  3 forms with a hidden field with the value of **step** and it is called in my index.php file to be call by a next button .my index file contains 
`<?php`

```
switch ($_POST['step']) {

    case 2:
        require_once 'form2.php';
        break;

    case 3:
        require_once 'form3.php';
        break;

    case 4:
        require_once 'form4.php';
        break;

    case 1:
    default:
        require_once 'form1.php';
}
```

?>

i want to store all value of input field when user input data(any time clicking the next button) in a multidimensional array, so that i can retrieve each value for my future use 
like for name field it is like a array ,how many time the user gives his name in the input field it will store in that name array ,like this others will be

i tried this also

```
<?php
 session_start();
 require_once 'form3.php';
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
     $_SESSION['POST'][$key][] = $value;
}
print_r($_SESSION); 
?>
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['post'] = $_SESSION;` doesn't work why?

Answer (score 0):

After this function:

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
$_SESSION['POST'][$key][] = $value;
}
```

At the first time the multidimensional subarray $_SESSION['POST'] will be made, at the next time all subarray $_SESSION['POST'] would be added to the multidimensional subarray $_SESSION['POST']['POST'] . You'll get unstructured array $_SESSION with the subarrays in the subarrays.

I think you need change the logic of the programm, like this:
sort the array $_POST and get all values with their keys in the the subarray $_SESSION['POST'],
next time if repeated key in the array $_POST add 1 to the $_SESSION['POST'][$key]['count'] or, if you want save all values of entered data save they in the subarray $_SESSION['POST'][$key][]. Get the last element you can by function end().

Comment: thanks a lot .you are right ,i work with the count variable ,by increment with the repeat button